# Add space between two words in a ::After Pseudo element CSS

Tags: css

I would like to add two extra spaces between the words TITLE and THE. So the word-spacing or text-indentation CSS property will not work here. Any advice to achieve my goal? Thank you.

```css
.c1::after{
content:"SUB TITLE THE EXAMPLE";
position:absolute;
display:block;
font-size:.395em;
letter-spacing:.125em;}
```

```html
<div class ="c1" style="display:flex; justify-content:center;"> 
   <h4>HELLO STACKOVERFLOW</h4></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\00a0` instead of spaces in the `content` property. They don't get collapsed into a single space.

```css
.c1::after{
    content: "SUB TITLE\00a0\00a0THE EXAMPLE";
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you for that quick response!!!!! Perfect solution.